# Python plot to PDF multiple figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple figures to one PDF but it generates corrupt PDF.

```
import sys, os, pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab, scipy.stats as stats, calendar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
def plotLineGraph(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
    df.plot(ax=ax)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    return fig

pp = PdfPages(r'C:\myPLOT.pdf')
for ii in [1,2,3,4]:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.rand(500), 'y':np.rand(500)})
    pp.savefig(plotGraph(df))
pp.close()
```

How should I modify the above code so that I get the 4 plots successfully in one PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several typos in your code.

1. The function is called `plotLineGraph` not `plotGraph`
2. `numpy` has no `rand`, it is `numpy.random.rand` instead.
3. You create a superfluous axes via `ax = plt.subplot(111)`. Remove that line.

Finally consider that writing to `C:\` directly is not allowed in some windows systems.
In total this would give:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def plotLineGraph(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
    df.plot(ax=ax)
    return fig

pp = PdfPages(r'D:\myPLOT.pdf')
for ii in [1,2,3,4]:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(500), 'y':np.random.rand(500)})
    pp.savefig(plotLineGraph(df))
pp.close()
```